# Pydantic is not reducing set to its unique items

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, pydantic

I have two pydantic models such that `Child` model is part of `Parent` model.
For both models the unique field is `name` field. However, when I create two `Child` instances with the same `name`(`"Child1"`), the `Parent.children` set unable to identify the duplicate children with the same name.

I am using Python 3.11.

```
import pydantic


class Child(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str

    __hash__ = object.__hash__

    def __str__(self):
        cls_name = self.__class__.__name__
        return f"{cls_name}({self.name})"

    # def __cmp__(self, other):
    #     return self.name == other.name


class Parent(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str
    children: set[Child] = set()

    def __str__(self):
        cls_name = self.__class__.__name__
        return f"{cls_name}({self.name}, children={self.children})"

data = dict(
    name="test",
    children=set([
        Child(name="Child1"),  
        Child(name="Child1"),
    ])
)

print(Parent(**data))

# Result: Parent(test, children={Child(name='Child1'), Child(name='Child1')})
# desired result is to have a single `Child` because both childrent have same `name`.
```

`Result: Parent(test, children={Child(name='Child1'), Child(name='Child1')})`
desired result is to have a single `Child` because both childrent have same `name`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why are you setting `__hash__ = object.__hash__`?

Comment: otherwise I am receiving `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Child'` when I am creating a `Child` instance.

Comment: Why do you think that your `Child` objects should hash based on that attribute? You are simply setting the hash dunder to `object.__hash__`, which hashes by *identity*. Note, it will be inconsistent with the way `__eq__` will be implemented for `pydantic.BaseModel` instances

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the comment by @juanpa I realized that `hash` should be based on the `child.name` field add have added the below code to the `Child` class.

```
def __hash__(self) -> str:
    return hash(self.name)
```

so that class looks like:

```
class Child(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str

    def __hash__(self) -> str:
        return hash(self.name)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        cls_name = self.__class__.__name__
        return f"{cls_name}({self.name})"
```